# Setting up OpenSSO (OpenAM) for Identity Provider scenario

Tags: saml-2.0, openam

We have an OpenSSO (OpenAM) instance set up at our end to work as a Service Provider (SP). It's been working well so far in an SP Initiated SSO scenario, however, I recently had to set it up for an IDP initiated scenario and am unable to get it to work successfully. To explain, in this scenario, the IDP would like to send the SAMLResponse directly to the Assertion consumer service at my end and our OpenAM instance should be able successfully digest the response and send the user to our underlying application. My questions are:

1. Is there any other configuration required in this scenario except for exchanging/uploading the metadata between the IDP and us (SP)?
2. Can I upload the metadata of the iDP in the same COT as the other IDPs that are currently working in the SP Initiate Scenario? Or should there be a new COT for each IDP provider?
3. What URL should I provide to the IDP to send the SAMLResponse to? Is it the AssertionConsumerService index="1" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" from our metadata? I tried this a few days back and OpenAM reported an error - "this is not the right consumer service for this request" or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for this on an OpenAM forum -

```
http://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/openam/2012-August/007872.html
```